# Phython - eliminating a certain data from strings

Tags: python, excel, pandas

New in Python. 
I have strings of info and in some rows of few columns 'nan' value shows up because a cell in excel is empty (and it should be empty). 
Question: how do I drop those values without dropping whole column?

```
#excel file and my desired output:
n1  b1  n2  b2  
1   2
1   2
1   2    3   4
1   2    3   4
```

## What i get:

```
n1  b1  n2  b2  
1   2 'nan' 'nan'
1   2 'nan' 'nan'
1   2    3   4
1   2    3   4
```

## what I have so far

```
for k in range(len(switched_shunt_data['I'])):
    f.write('{:>6},'.format(str(switched_shunt_data['N1'][k]).encode('utf-8')) + \
            '{:>2},'.format(switched_shunt_data['N1'][k]) + \
            '{:>8},'.format(switched_shunt_data['B1'][k]) + \
            if switched_shunt_data['N2'][k] == 'nan':
                .drop(switched_shunt_data['N2'][k])
            else:
                '{:>2},'.format(switched_shunt_data['N2'][k])
            '{:>8},'.format(switched_shunt_data['B2'][k]) + '\n')
```

Comment: What are you trying to replace them with? Unless I'm missing something, you can't drop individual values - that would leave a hole in your table and that doesn't make sense!

Comment: Please show us a minimum working example and what you want to achieve at the end.

Comment: I'm creating a strings and converting excel data into raw data. 
So i have a string that contains N1, B1, N2, B2 columns but some of my entries(rows) do not have N2 and B2 entries, instead they are blank. And when I write raw file those rows which do not have any value for N2 and B2 give 'nan' value. 
I would like to stop writing the string for those rows where N2 and B2 shows as 'nan'

Comment: What do you want to put in those cells instead of 'nan'?

Answer (score 0):

For "nan" (not a number) values, write an empty string.

Use 2 single or double quote characters for the empty string values.